# Error in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

So we keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Indications/Error.aspx
~/Views/Indications/Error.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

when doing a multitude of things. It happens randomly, and sometimes happens doing the same exact thing that we just did without an error. Even when we catch an error in javascript sometimes, it still throws this error on the backend. Sometimes it navigates the user to a generic "Server Error" page as well.

What is a way we can handle this and display some information about the source of the issue? This stack isn't showing much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your action method (or controller) has the [HandleError] attribute set on it? If that's the case and you don't have Error.aspx, then you will see this error. If you remove the [HandleError] attribute, you will be able to see the actual error.